# why is the Go compiled version is relatively huge?

Tags: compilation, go

I recently installed go and was trying out hello world example.

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main() {
    fmt.Printf("hello, world\n")
}
```

> $ go build hello.go

returns hello binary file which is 1.2Mb size. Thats comparatively huge for just a hello world program. Any particular reason on why is the file size large ? Is it because of importing "fmt" ?

Comment: It statically compiles in all the dependencies unstripped. Imagine the ease of deployment!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [a Go FAQ](http://golang.org/doc/faq#Why_is_my_trivial_program_such_a_large_binary)

**Why is my trivial program such a large binary?**

> The linkers in the gc tool chain (5l, 6l, and 8l) do static linking.
>   All Go binaries therefore include the Go run-time, along with the
>   run-time type information necessary to support dynamic type checks,
>   reflection, and even panic-time stack traces.
>
> A simple C "hello, world" program compiled and linked statically using
>   gcc on Linux is around 750 kB, including an implementation of printf.
>   An equivalent Go program using fmt.Printf is around 1.2 MB, but that
>   includes more powerful run-time support.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, package "fmt" is one of the reasons. It also in turn imports other packages. But even without using "fmt", there's the whole runtime statically linked into a Go binary. And Go's runtime is not a simple one - it includes for instance a scheduler/goroutine vs OS thread manager, split stack allocator, the garbage collector and garbage collector friendly memory allocator which is also C threads friendly, signal handlers and stack trace generator, ...